# install APK from my server in secure way

Tags: android

I wants to install application(APK) from my server. what is the best
approach for it. I wants to not to stolen my apk in any way by anyone.
except root device.Just for now i am downloading apk from server to
SDCard and install it then remove it from SDCard. User can stole it
from SDCard.

Comment: Sadly, I'm afraid you WILL have to store it somewhere at a moment or another. And by the way, if it's on a rooted device, one can find the installed APK easily and copy it too, so even then your APK wouldn't be really safe.

Comment: Don't waste your time attempting the unachievable, as a user can copy the installed APK off a device even *without* rooting it.  If you want to control things, make your app require the assistance of server infrastructure (at least now and then), for actual functionality (not just security checks), make the server require a user account, and control account creation to authorized users only.